# flex: problem displaying custom dataTipRenderer correctly

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a flex AreaChart with a custom dataTipRenderer:

```
<mx:AreaChart id="numParticipants" 
                  dataProvider="{UsersModel.graphData.data_points.point}" 
                  seriesFilters="[]" right="10" left="10" 
                  top="10" bottom="10" fontSize="9" color="#8D8D8D"
                  dataTipRenderer="tooltip.ChartTooltip"
                  showDataTips="true" dataTipMode="multiple" mouseSensitivity="10">
```

the renderer code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" top="5" width="154" height="42">

    <mx:Style source="css/style.css"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import models.UsersModel;
                import mx.charts.HitData;           
            import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                //trace("ChartTooltip: x=" + x + " y=" + y);
                    var dataPoint:HitData = value as HitData;
                    var date:Date = new Date();
                var units:String = UsersModel.graphData.units;

                    date.setTime(dataPoint.item.timestamp * 1000);

                switch (units)
                {
                    case "days":
                        txtDate.text = dayFormatter.format(date);
                    break;
                case "hours":
                    txtDate.text = hourFormatter.format(date);
                    break;
            }
            txtUsers.text = dataPoint.item.participants;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:DateFormatter id="hourFormatter" formatString="L:NN A"/>
<mx:DateFormatter id="dayFormatter" formatString="MMM DD"/>
<mx:Image source="@Embed('images/BaloonLeft.png')" x="0" width="25" height="42" y="0" maintainAspectRatio="false" />
<mx:Image source="@Embed('images/BaloonCenter.png')" x="25" width="120" height="42" y="0" maintainAspectRatio="false"/>
<mx:Image source="@Embed('images/BaloonRight.png')" x="145" width="9" height="42" y="0" maintainAspectRatio="false" />
<mx:VBox x="25" width="120" height="42" y="0" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalGap="0">
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="Date:" styleName="dataTooltipText" fontWeight="bold"/>
        <mx:Label id="txtDate" styleName="dataTooltipText"/>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="Users:" styleName="dataTooltipText" fontWeight="bold"/>
        <mx:Label id="txtUsers" styleName="dataTooltipText"/>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:VBox>
```

The tooltip shows correctly for some data points, but for others it doesn't look fine.

Here is a screen capture of how it looks:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/91145267@N00/6025401750/in/photostream

Any ideas why??

Many thanks!

Ofer

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to place the Images and the content within a custom layoutContainer such as a HBox:

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Image source="@Embed('images/BaloonLeft.png')" x="0" width="25" height="42" y="0" maintainAspectRatio="false" />
    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:Image source="@Embed('images/BaloonCenter.png')" x="25" width="120" height="42" y="0" maintainAspectRatio="false"/>

        <mx:VBox x="25" width="120" height="42" y="0" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalGap="0">
            <mx:HBox>
                <mx:Label text="Date:" styleName="dataTooltipText" fontWeight="bold"/>
                <mx:Label id="txtDate" styleName="dataTooltipText"/>
            </mx:HBox>
            <mx:HBox>
                <mx:Label text="Users:" styleName="dataTooltipText" fontWeight="bold"/>
                <mx:Label id="txtUsers" styleName="dataTooltipText"/>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Image source="@Embed('images/BaloonRight.png')" x="145" width="9" height="42" y="0" maintainAspectRatio="false" />
</mx:HBox>
```

I haven't really tested this, but I wanted to give you the main Idea. The HBox layouts everything horizontally and the Canvas I introduced makes it possible to draw the background and the content over each other. As I mentioned ... I hope it gives you the general Idea.

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris and thanks for the quick response. I tried your suggestion (with minor adjustments) but I still get the exact same result. So my guess is that it is not related to the graphical elements layout, since some of the tips are displayed correctly as can be seen in the screen capture. Still looking for more ideas... Thanks!